# How to auto increment the nchar column in Sql Server

Tags: triggers, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the table as ReasonMaster as

```
ReasonId nchar(10),Reason varchar(50),EntLog datetime.
```

Content as:

```
ReasonId  Reason
--------- -------
REA00001  Ask For Leave
```

After adding new record I have to generate next column of ReasonId as REA00002 automatically

Comment: It would be better to have a purely numeric identity column that will just work immediately. You can then *format* that number by converting to a fixed number of digits and adding a textual prefix - as either a computed column, in a view, or in your front end. There is rarely, if ever, a need to *store* this value precomposed like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the next id like this

```
select 'REA' + right('00000' + cast(max(right(ReasonId, 5)) + 1 as varchar), 5)
from ReasonMaster
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/43cc3/7)

Comment: it Gives me an error as 
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'REA001  ' to data type int.